# How to display the image of the user who is currently speaking in a channel, Flutter Agora agora_rtc_engine?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, agora.io

Im using Agora SDK along with Flutter for a project,
I have gone through the SDK Documentation but could not make out the requirement im currently having,

Lets say there is a channel with 100 Users
and User modal is like

```
User{
String name;
String imageUrl;
}
```

I would like to update the ui for all 100 user by displaying the image of the current user who is speaking in the channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to add uid in your user modal and then use the activeSpeaker callback provided in the SDK,
activeSpeaker callback returns the uid of the user who is speaking currently and you can use that uid to display the user video or in your case the image of that user.
Have a look at the documentation over here:[activeSpeaker documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/live-streaming/API%20Reference/flutter/rtc_channel/RtcChannelEventHandler/activeSpeaker.html)